Competing Risk Analysis without censoring
In our study we are interested how the presence of a set of diseases (le'ts call it "cause_disease", with the levels a, b, c, and d) effects what other diseases patients will develop in future (let's call it "event_disease", with the levels X, Y and Z). Out data looks like this:
id    cause_disease    months_to_follow_up    event_disease
1     a                1.5                    Y
2     c                7.0                    X
3     a                3.8                    Y
...   ...              ...                    ...

Since we are interested in the transition to one of the three possible "event_diseases" X, Y and Z, we run a Compiting Risk Analysis. Therefore, we made a dummy coding matrix for "cause_disease" and did the following in R:
cmprsk::crr(ftime= months_to_follow_up, fstatus= event_disease, group = cause_disease_dummy)

The function cmprsk::crr() has an argument called cencode where one can specify what entry in the outcomes defines a censored case. This makes sense since time to event analysis are often right censored data. But in our data there is no censoting at all. All dat is complete. Can we simply leave out the censoring definition or does it violate some assumption/ relies on a different distribution or so? The math of the cmprsk::crr() is based on: Fine JP and Gray RJ (1999) A proportional hazards model for the subdistribution of a competing risk. JASA 94:496-509.
All I found on this topic is this question with no answer.

It would be strange for there to be absolutely no right censoring, as it would require all individuals to have experienced the "event_disease" regardless of how brief the follow-up time might have been. The lack of censoring leads to questions that perhaps you have omitted individuals with short follow up, or have identified individuals for the study based on having already had the "event_disease" and then looked backwards for evidence/timing of the "cause_disease."
Omitting individuals with short follow up might lead to bias. Identifying individuals based on having already had the "event_disease" leads to right truncation; see Section 5.3 of Klein and Moeschberger for the methods needed in that case.
If you have avoided those traps, then there is no need for survival data to contain censored event times. You might consider whether a Fine-Gray competing risks model is what you really want. If you do, make sure that you understand what the underlying "subdistribution" represents. It's possible instead to use a multi-state survival model, which more readily provides information about probability of being in one of the competing states as a function of time. The R multi-state model vignette has a useful overview of those different approaches.

It is indeed the case that at follow up every patient has one level of "event disease". In fact, it is not really a event "disease" but that are different phenotypes and each patient can be linked to one phenotype. Something like "every person has a blood type". Hard to explain all the theory behind the study and wanted to keep it simple. Thanks!
